# What is the type of `peer` for `DTLSv1_listen`?

Tags: c++, openssl, dtls

I'm trying to implement a DTLS server following https://gist.github.com/Jxck/b211a12423622fe304d2370b1f1d30d5, but i'm running into trouble at `DTLSv1_listen`. I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.1c, and the `peer` arg from `DTLSv1_listen` appears to have type of `BIO_ADDR *`. I'm confused as to how to use it, as the documentation isn't really helpful. The tutorial just passes in a `sockaddr *` (or was it `sockaddr_in6`?) to peer. Would that work? If not, how can I convert a `BIO_ADDR *` to a `sockaddr *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new BIO_ADDR object using `BIO_ADDR_new`. So something like this:

```
    BIO_ADDR *addr = BIO_ADDR_new();
    int ret;

    if (addr == NULL)
        goto err;

    ret = DTLSv1_listen(ssl, addr);

    /* Handle the result of DTLSv1_listen */


    BIO_ADDR_free(addr);
```

You can examine the contents of the BIO_ADDR using the various getter functions available. See the BIO_ADDR documentation here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_ADDR.html

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at https://github.com/nplab/DTLS-Examples/blob/master/src/dtls_udp_echo.c, it seems as if `BIO_ADDR` is equivalent to

```
struct {
    sockaddr_storage sockStorage;
    sockaddr_in6 sock6;
    sockaddr_in sock4;
}
```